# Is this a valid way to show a sequence does not split?

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

Suppose you have 
$$
0\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\to 0
$$
viewed as additive groups. Let $i$ be the inclusion of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Q}$. I want to say this is not a split sequence, since there is no retract $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f\circ i=id_\mathbb{Z}$. If there were, then $f(n)=n$ for all integers $n$. Then 
$$
nf(1/n)=f(1/n)\cdots+f(1/n)=f(1/n+\cdots+1/n)=f(1)=1
$$
so $f(1/n)=1/n$, which doesn't make any sense if $n>1$, since $f(1/n)\in\mathbb{Z}$. So no such $f$ exists. Is that all there is to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! That is good. You're basically observing that $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})=\{0\}$ and so you clearly can't have a retraction.

You could also note that if it split then $\mathbb{Q}\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$, but $\mathbb{Q}$ has no torsion :)

Comment: okie thanks for confirming for me.

Comment: @YNChew No problem :) If you're happy with my answer, you can accept it so that others know you don't need more help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes; this is the extension lemma, and it holds in Abelian categories:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma